# Resizable and Rearrangable CollectionView Cell with Image: Swift or Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, layout, uicollectionview

> My CollectionView Cell has only Image in it. I want to resize that
>   image by user, and while resizing the image all the cell should
>   automatically rearrange (I have fixed image count i. e. 22):

[image: this how my entire collection view should look like with image in cell]

- I have used flow layout for
  collection view but limitation is that needs fixed number of
  height/width.
- I have added resized library separately.

> I Tried by searching many libraries and doing so many demos but not
>   able to get the required output. I want you to suggest me either the
>   way should i go with or If you have done such kind of stuff then your
>   thought are welcome.

*Thank you in advance.*

Comment: use collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath method to change the size and store each cell size in a different array named sizeArray and update the every indexed size by creating a custom logic of proportion when user try to change size of a single image and then update all the indexes size in sizeArray.
After updating the size in sizeArray simply update the collection View.

Comment: some how looking ok ok, i will try to implement and let you know.. Thank you!